# Groovy in Jenkinsfile hangs when posting to an URL

Tags: groovy, http-post, jenkins-pipeline

I have following method in Jenkinsfile used to retrieve data from given URL (posting json to it and reading the output).
Calling it in Jenkins causes the build to hang with *Proceeding.." text.

```
@NonCPS                                                      
def callService(server, method, params = '') {                                  
    final HttpURLConnection connection = "http://$server:8080/router/".toURL().openConnection()
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");                                        
    connection.setRequestProperty('Accept', 'application/json;charset=utf-8')   
    connection.setRequestProperty('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=utf-8')
    connection.setDoOutput(true)                                                
    connection.outputStream.withWriter { Writer writer ->                       
        writer << """{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "$method", "params": {$params}}"""
    }                                                                           
    String text = connection.inputStream.withReader { Reader reader -> reader.text }
    return text                                                                                                                                                                               
}
```

And the call of this method:

```
servers = ["example1"]
for (int i = 0; i < servers.size(); i++) {                                  
    server = servers[i]                                                     
    assert callService(server, 'VersionService:getVersionDetails').matches('.*build:[1-9][0-9]*.*') 
}
```

Is the above code correct groovy one, or am I doing something wrong that causes the code to freeze?

When I do the same thing using curl, it works:

```
curl -v -H 'Accept: application/json;charset=utf-8' -H 'Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8' -d '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method":"VersionService:getVersionDetails", "params":{}}' http://example1:8080/router/
```

Comment: Does it eventually timeout?

Comment: No, it hangs there forever. When I do curl equivalent it works correctly.

Comment: @tim_yates maybe reader.text waits for the end line? The response doesn't contain the endline for sure.

Comment: Just a note: if you already have Groovy, then use `groovyx.net.http.RESTClient`. It is easier than plain `HttpURLConnection`

Comment: @Nikem I tried, but it appears it is not in the standard groovy build, but an outside library, which I don't know how to use in Jenkinsfile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not with groovy reading of the HTTP response but with broken [jenkins-pipeline](/questions/tagged/jenkins-pipeline), it hangs the build if an `assert` fails (reported already https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-34488).

So the solution for now is to write your own `assert`, e.g.:

```
def asrt(value) {                                          
    if (!value) {                                          
        throw new IllegalStateException("failed assertion")
    }                                                      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Six years have passed since this question is asked, it's late for a new answer. But since this is one of the top links in google search "jenkins httpRequest is hung", will paste our solution here:
The "http request" plugin in Jenkins is 1.8.X, after updating to 1.11, the "httpRequest" hung issue is fixed.